# Jquery inapropriate onclick fire

Tags: jquery, onclick

If I try to click any of the buttons, I am just checking if it is class name "sale" exist or not inside that anther onclick to save, example if I click on the PENDING button I don't want to save but when I click any of the buttons it's firing the submit click

If I click PENDING or REMOVE button it won't fire

```
$('.submit').on("click",function(){
```

just simply console "No Action"

https://jsfiddle.net/alimuhammadtn/5co7431a/3/

```js
$(function() {
  $('.action').on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('sale')) {
      $('.submit').on("click", function() {
        console.log('##saved....')
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No action');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="action sale">
  <input type="button" class="submit" value="SALE"> <br>
</div>
<div class="action pending">
  <input type="button" class="submit" value="PENDING"> <br>
</div>
<div class="action remove">
  <input type="button" class="submit" value="REMOVE">
</div>
```

Comment: Your code does not make any sense. Attach event handlers to the buttons only and not to the div or cancel the event bubbling

Comment: attaching event handlers is old style,please check in jsfiddle link and suggest solutions

Comment: Perhaps you mean: `if $(this).closest("div").is(".sale")) ...`

Comment: Using class names, it doesnt means using tag

Comment: `.on` is attaching an event handler. What are you talking about "old style" ???

Comment: What about [this](https://jsfiddle.net/q124kdch/)? is this what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want from your description, but I think you mean this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.submit').on("click", function() {
//        if ($(this).closest("div").is('.sale')) {
    if ($(this).parent().is('.sale')) {
        console.log('##saved....')
    } else {
      console.log('No action');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="action sale">
  <input type="button" class="submit" value="SALE"> <br>
</div>
<div class="action pending">
  <input type="button" class="submit" value="PENDING"> <br>
</div>
<div class="action remove">
  <input type="button" class="submit" value="REMOVE">
</div>
```

But why not this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.submit').on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).is('#sale')) {
        console.log('##saved....')
    } else {
      console.log('No action');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="action">
  <input type="button" class="submit" id="sale" value="SALE" />
</div>
<div class="action">
  <input type="button" class="submit" id="pending" value="PENDING" />
</div>
<div class="action">
  <input type="button" class="submit" id="remove" value="REMOVE" />
</div>
```

Comment: The result is i expected. could you please any suggetion using the class name intead of Tagname?